# Better way to dynamically add LOTS of views

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that has a `ViewPager` that shows a calendar on each page. Right now, I'm using a `MonthDisplayHelper` to figure out where each date goes. Right now, I'm dynamically creating my layout with a `LinearLayout` for each row, and then equally spaced `RelativeLayout`s for each day, each of which have two `TextView`s in them. As you can imagine, this is pretty slow, and it takes more than a second to load every page. Does anyone know of a way to reuse views or something to make this faster?

(Also, if this is a bad place for this question, let me know and I'll remove it right away.)

Thanks!

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using one of the existing calendar widgets, such as `CalendarView` (and its backport: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/ics-calendarview/), or `ExtendedCalendarView` (http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/)?

Comment: If you can make a screenshot of your view and post it. it will be great! Thanks.

Comment: It needs to be compatible with Gingerbread.

Comment: @Jarvis screenshot is up

Comment: Ok! we understand better with a screenshot! use a GRIDVIEW for your calendar. Gridview is like a listview, you just rewrite the getView() mehod for your adapter.

Comment: @Jarvis - I've tried that, but I can try again - last time, I think I also had a database query slowing me down. Anyway, if you think of anything else that could help, that would be great.

Comment: Ok, if I have an idea I will contact you! ;)